# Directly import typescript module with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created react by `create-react-app my-app --typescript`.

And then I installed typescript module in local.

`../typescript-module/A.ts`

```
export default class A {
}
```

`App.ts`

```
import A from 'typescript-module/A';
console.log(A);
```

I try to import typescript module to my react app.
But it show error like under.

```
./node_modules/typescript-module/A.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
```

How can I set installing local typescript module ?

Comment: Did you remove previous create-react-app installs first? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6119#issuecomment-451614035

Comment: Is your webpack file setup to handle typescript loaders?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are trying to import a local custom made React component. If you use an absolute path for your import, it will try to find it in the node_modules. You should use relative paths for local modules/components.

`import 'typescript-module/A'` -> `import './typescript-module/A'`

Note: The relative path depends on where you are importing it from